# Moving all contacts from CiviCRM to Kepla

Tags: database, export, civicrm-home, migration

my organisation is currently switching from CiviCRM to Kepla. I'm wondering about the best way to export all contacts information out of Civi and import it into Kepla. I have been able to export individual lists of people into an excel document, clean it up, and import them individually, however there are so many contacts left and I'm worried about people falling through the cracks. If there's a way to export all contacts from the database at once, including the notes attached to them, that would be ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the quick search or any other search and simply enter "%" as a search criteria. This would bring up all contacts in the database and you could export them afterwards.

If you want to include deleted contacts use the advanced search with the same criteria but tick the box "Search in Trash (deleted contacts)".

In the export dialogue, make sure to select all columns you want, including notes.